# Grant permission to a particular directory to avoid java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: java, permissions, policy, securitymanager

I am trying to read a text file after I have set the security manager with a policy file which is-

```
grant  
{
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/home/esamsar/NetBeansProjects/FilePermissionDemo/src/cheese.txt", "write";
};
```

It is working fine but when I add a codebase to it java.security.AccessControlException is encountered everytime.
My OS is Ubuntu and I have tried the following and all are encountering the same exception.

```
grant codebase  "file:/home/esamsar/NetBeansProjects/FilePermissionDemo/src/*"
grant codebase  "file://home/esamsar/NetBeansProjects/FilePermissionDemo/src/*"
grant  codebase "/home/esamsar/NetBeansProjects/FilePermissionDemo/src/*"
```

Could someone point the proper way to add a codebase to grant permission to a particular directory.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your stacktrace. Why does your codebase include a `src` directory? It should consist of JAR files, or at worst of directories of .class files. The source directory won't be there at runtime.

Comment: Thanks.There a security exception thrown now after using   grant  codebase "file://home/esamsar/NetBeansProjects/FilePermissionDemo/build/classes/*".I am using textFile.canWrite(); which leads to the same exception.

Comment: Unless and until you post your stack trace as requested your question cannot be answered. I would also like to see the relevant output when run with -Djava.security.debug=access,failure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
grant codebase "file:///home/esamsar/NetBeansProjects/FilePermissionDemo/classes/-" {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/home/esamsar/NetBeansProjects/FilePermissionDemo/src/cheese.txt", "write";
};
```

The point here is to allow the folder where your IDE is outputing the compiled classes (here I supposed `<your_project_path>/classes`), ending with `/-`.